# Bootstrap Carousel and <img> tag with object-fit & object-position not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel, object-fit

I have the following carousel:

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      ...
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="Images/pastry3.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
    </div>
      ...
  </div>
```

and I have the following CSS:

```
.carousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

    .carousel .carousel-inner, .carousel .carousel-item {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .carousel-item img {
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: 50% 50%;
    }
```

I have images that are much larger than the screen (width: 100% and height: 100%) and I'd like them to be `img`s that can maintain their aspect ratios while being in the center of the screen, hence `object-fit: cover;` and `object-position: 50% 50%`, but it isn't working. Why?

I'm trying to make a full-screen practice home page with sliding images/videos with different text areas in different slides.

Comment: Could someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: If you want to grab attention towards your question you can always start a bounty after two days.

Comment: take a look at this (CSS-Only Technique #1) https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same problem until I did this:

```
.carousel-item img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

I hope this helps someone :)

Comment: THANK YOU. This fixed my issue. Note that if you are using a smaller slider you can change the height to a fixed height and it works as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need in the image:

```
height:100%;
max-width:100%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.carousel-item img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I will take care of this from now on wards. Thanks